# leaflet routing.control update when marker is moved

Tags: leaflet

I am using leaflet and routing.control to show a route. I have it working fine, but I would like one of the markers to move with the users location using watch.position. But for now I a just trying to move the marker when I click a button. Again this works fine but when the marker moves I would like the route to update automatically. Its possible if you  drag the marker so surely its possible when marker is moved  in a different way? I can it if I remove the control and add a new one but this flickers too much. Any advice?

The code for the routing.control is

```
myroute = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(window.my_lat, window.my_lng),
    L.latLng(window.job_p_lat, window.job_p_lng)
  ],show: true, units: 'imperial',
 router: L.Routing.mapbox('API KEY HERE'),
  createMarker: function(i, wp, nWps) {
    if (i === 0 || i === nWps + 1) {
      return mymarker = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
        icon: redIcon
      });
    } else {
      return job_start = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
        icon: greenIcon
      }); 
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

and the code for moving the marker is

```
function movemarker() {
    var lat = "52.410490";
    var lng = "-1.575950";  
    var newLatLng = new L.LatLng(lat, lng);
    mymarker.setLatLng(newLatLng);
    // I assume I call something here?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted, I did it with this, which removes first point and replaces it with new data

```
myroutewithout.spliceWaypoints(0, 1, newLatLng);
```